# React Native - Horizontal FlatList in multiple line

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, react-native-flatlist, horizontallist

I have created a FlatList in which all the item are horizontal scrollable. I want to add a functionality when screen width ends so that next item must come in next line.

Please help.

```
 <FlatList
            data={item.label}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            horizontal
            renderItem={({item, index}) => (
             <View></View>
             )}
            numColumns={1}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff',}}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            bounces={false}
          />
```

using this I am able to add only horizontal list but not able to divide it into next line when screen ends.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: so you do not want the list to scroll horizontally and go to next line instead, right?

Comment: @SubialIjaz Yes, correct